# Notify parallel Components about changes

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

i try to notify parallel components (rendered with v-for) about changes.
This is my markup:

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.ID">
    <my-component :item="item"></my-component> 
</div>
```

And now, if for example something in the first instance of "my-component" changes all remaining "my-component"s should be notified about his change. How can i achieve that?

(At the moment i use this.$root.$emit and this.$root.$on)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can achieve this:

#### 1. Use props

VueJS' data-flow patterns recommend passing props down and bubbling events up. You could use this pattern by having a prop that is passed down that notifies the child components about the change.

**Parent**

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.ID">
    <my-component :item="item" :last-modified="lastModified"></my-component> 
</div>
```

**Child**

```
<script>
export default {
  ...
  watch: {
    lastModified (v) {
      // Do something
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### 2. Use Vuex

Another way to achieve this is to use Vuex for global state management. This is the recommended option particularly if you're already using Vuex to manage state.

**Parent**

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.ID">
    <my-component :item="item"></my-component> 
</div>
```

**Child**

```
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  ...
  computed: {
    mapGetters([
      'lastModified'
    ]),
    ...
  },
  watch: {
    lastModified (v) {
      // Do something
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### 2. Use $refs

Another simple way to achieve this on a small-scale is to use [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements).

**Parent**

```
<template>
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.ID">
    <my-component :item="item" :last-modified="lastModified" ref="childComponents"></my-component> 
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  watch: {
    lastModified () {
      for (const child of this.$refs.childComponents) {
        child.onModified()
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Child**

```
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    onModified () {
      // Do something
    }
  }
}
```

#### 4. Use an event bus

This is a very handy way of achieving event propagation, but is [not recommended](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Non-flux-state-management-use-with-caution). For this approach, we will create a *third* component, that is a simple vue instance that will be used for events.

**bus.vue**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default new Vue()
```

**Parent**

```
<template>
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.ID">
    <my-component :item="item"></my-component> 
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Bus from 'bus'

export default {
  ...
  watch: {
    lastModified () {
      Bus.$emit('modified')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Child**

```
<script>
import Bus from 'bus'
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    onModified () {
      // Do something
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    Bus.$on('modified', this.onModified)
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    Bus.$off('modified', this.onModified)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpflul. I decided to use the ref variant.